# How can I connect a Lan Server in Linux Terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal

Yeah, that is my question. I'm living in a school's dorm and using school's internet. We have a server on this internet network . What i should for connect this server. (I have a Server ip, server port, and my ID , pw . In system Programming courses we are putty for connect to server)

thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very basic. Command is ;

```
$ ssh userName@ipAdress
```